# How to determine which interfaces a Linux socket is bound to in C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. Given a Linux socket, how can I

1. Determine if it is bound?
2. If it is bound, determine which subset of network interfaces it bound to on a multihomed system?

In short I have a machine with multiple network cards and a socket that is only bound to a subset of these cards. I want to programmatically detect and log these interfaces after they have been bound else where in our libraries meaning I don't have access to this infnormation at the time of binding.

I should also point out that I need an IPV4/6 compatible solution preferably for that works with SCTP sockets (though I'm fine with UDP or TCP solutions for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [getsockname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) function returns socket name i.e. the local socket address. Just call this function for a unbound and a bound socket to determine your socket implementations behavior.

**EDIT**:
When you have an AF_INET (i.e. IPv4) socket, the member `sin_addr.S_un.S_addr` is identical to the appropriate member in the `SOCKADDR_IN` struct that you have passed to the `bind` function. So if you have bound to `INADDR_ANY` you get `INADDR_ANY` when the socket isn't bound to a specific network adapter.

I checked this with the socket implementation of my OS (Windows 7). If your implementation returns something else, you might experience an undefined behavior caused by a bug somewhere else. Of course you can verify the implementation of the network stack if you have the source code available.

There is no support for binding to a subset of network adapters. You can only bind to one or all.

Comment: How would this work for cases where the socket is bound to multiple interfaces?

Comment: How would you bind a socket to multiple interfaces? The function `bind` accepts one struct sock_addr`.

Comment: It may be bound with INADDR_ANY or in6addr_any which technically is all interfaces. I apologize for my bad wording above. The problem I'm seeing is that I'm not getting back this as the interface/host when I call getsockname(). Instead I'm seeing what is apparently garbage. Shouldn't I get back something indicating INADDR_ANY or in6addr_any?

Comment: I am accepting your answer as I believe the error is in fact a bug. I am working SCTP IPv6 Sockets on SLES 10 SP3 Linux and just wanted to verify I wasn't losing my mind as I couldn't find any bug reports of similar issues.